# Edit an item after it has been inserted

Tags: android

I'm new at android, since i'm watching tutorials. As following i learned to do a listview in one of them, but they didn't put a update function. As so i tried to do that myself, but with no success. Can you help me? Here's the code i have.
Thank you

```
public void updateTask(View view) {
    View parent = (View) view.getParent();
    TextView taskTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.update(Task.TaskEntry.TABLE, null, Task.TaskEntry.COL_ITEM_TITLE + " = ?", new String[]{task});
    db.close();
    updateUI();  
} }
```

The problem is this update function i can't get to work. Otherwise my app works fine
I don't know if i need create other strings to create new values or other thing

'I've been trying different methods to update but just crashed everytime. I don't know if i need to change something or i'm not using db.update in the right away`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `RecyclerView` to show a list of data in your application.

You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

You can use the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of the `RecyclerView.Adapter` class, or the `notifyItemInserted()` with the `index` to notify the adapter that an item has been inserted at the particular index.

This post [here](https://suragch.medium.com/updating-data-in-an-android-recyclerview-842e56adbfd8) can help you get a better in detail understanding.

Comment: I saw people using db.update without creating a RecyclerView. I wanted to do that instead of begin all again. Maybe its because im not inserting the right data in mt updateTask?

Comment: can you add a link to the tutorial / article you are following?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoQM4sD--w0&t=944s&ab_channel=Yaz%C4%B1l%C4%B1mHub its this one. So i created a button to update in the window where he created the delete button. The problem is, when i tried to create the fuction in Main Activity, i just can´t figure it out how to do it. thanks for ur help